# Azure App Service Certificate ssl to AKS ingress

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, azure-keyvault

I have bought a WildCard ssl certificate from Azure App Service Certificate. I also have an AKS Cluster. I want to put it in the secret and use in ingress. After purchase it stored secret file in Azure Key Vault. I downloaded it and then imported to create Azure Key Vault Certificate. Then with akv2k8s I created a secret file in my AKS and used it in ingress. After my application threw 'err_cert_authority_invalid' error.
Do I do anything wrong ??
There is not so many documentation on ssl and ingress. In many articles, they use 'Lets Encrypt' or 'Cert Manager'.

https://akv2k8s.io/

[image]

Answer (score 2):

•   It can be due to the misinterpretation that the certificate is issued by the staging environment or vice versa. Thus, for that purpose, I would suggest you to please check the **‘stable/wordpress’** helm chart with the ingress annotation **'certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer': 'letsencrypt-staging'**. This will result in being issued a certificate from the fake issuer. Thus, even if your certificate is ingressed in your AKS as a secret, it will be shown as being issued from a fake issuer since the chain of certificate hash validation is broken in between. Please find below the curl for that purpose: -

```
   ‘ # curl -vkI https://blog.my-domain.com/
     ...
     * Server certificate:
     *  subject: CN=blog.my-domain.com
     *  start date: May 13 08:51:13 2019 GMT
     *  expire date: Aug 11 08:51:13 2019 GMT
     *  issuer: CN=Fake LE Intermediate X1
     ... ‘
```

Then, list the ingresses as follows: -

```
  ‘ # kubectl get ing
    NAME             HOSTS                              ADDRESS          PORTS     AGE
    blog-wordpress   blog.my-domain.com   35.200.214.186   80, 443   8m48s ’
```

and the certificates too: -

```
  ‘ # kubectl get certificates
    NAME                  READY   SECRET                AGE
    wordpress.local-tls   True    wordpress.local-tls   9m ’
```

Then, switch the issuer of the certificate to the one that has issued the certificate originally as below: -

```
   ‘ # kubectl edit ing blog-wordpress ’
```

And update the annotation as below: -

```
  ‘ certmanager.k8s.io/cluster-issuer: letsencrypt-prod ’
```

Once the ingress manifest is updated, then the certificate manifest will automatically be updated. To verify it, open the manifest for **‘wordpress.local-tls’** certificate resource as below: -

```
 ‘ kubectl edit certificate wordpress.local-tls ’
```

The issuer will be seen as updated as below: -

```
‘ kubectl edit certificate wordpress.local-tls ’
```

Thus, in this way, you will be able to import a certificate secret in AKS. For more details, I would suggest you to please refer the below link for more details: -

https://github.com/vmware-archive/kube-prod-runtime/issues/532